# Cannot access dynamic controls

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have some trouble when i'm trying to click my dynamic controls in StackPanel.
I'm adding controls to Grid in this way...

```
void Opt()
    {
        TextBlock Title_1 = new TextBlock();
        TextBlock Title_2 = new TextBlock();
        CheckBox Kwota_exists = new CheckBox();
        TextBox Title = new TextBox();
        StackPanel Frame = new StackPanel();
        Button OK = new Button();

        Title_1.Text = "Dodaj kategorię";
        Title_2.Text = "Aktywne kategorię";
        Kwota_exists.Content = "Stała kwota?";
        Title.Text = "Nazwa kategorii";
        OK.Content = "Dodaj";
        OK.IsEnabled = true;
        OK.IsHitTestVisible = true;
        OK.IsTabStop = true;
        OK.ClickMode = ClickMode.Release;
        Frame.IsHitTestVisible = true;

        Kwota_exists.Checked +=Kwota_exists_Checked;

        Title_1.FontSize = 50;
        Title_2.FontSize = 50;
        Title.FontSize = 20;
        Frame.Height = 100;
        Frame.Width = 400;

        Title_1.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
        Title_2.Margin = new Thickness(0, 220, 0, 0);
        Frame.Margin = new Thickness(0, 70, 0, 0);

        Frame.HorizontalAlignment = Windows.UI.Xaml.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        Frame.VerticalAlignment = Windows.UI.Xaml.VerticalAlignment.Top;
        Frame.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;

        Frame.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(145, 56, 234, 21));

        Frame.Children.Add(Kwota_exists);
        Frame.Children.Add(Title);
        Frame.Children.Add(OK);


        GrdContent.Children.Add(Frame);
        GrdContent.Children.Add(Title_1);
        GrdContent.Children.Add(Title_2);

    }
```

But when i'm trying to click button or check checkbox controls doesn't seem to response (unclickable).
Looks like i can't access them or i'm doing something wrong. I would be gradefull if someone explain me where i'm doing mistake.

Comment: Any reason you are creating these through code? What type is GrdContent? If it is a Grid it looks like you are adding Title_1 and Title_2 over the Frame

Comment: Don't create or manipulate UI elements in XAML Based technologies. Use an `ItemsControl` instead.

Comment: Uhm, i'm just tryying to keep everything one one BlankPage and yes GrdContent is Grid is this make any difference?